# ASIO strand::wrap does it not have to serialize in order?

Tags: multithreading, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm lost on the distinction between posting using strand::wrap and a strand::post? Seems like both guarantee serialization yet how can you serialize with wrap and not get consistent order? Seems like they both would have to do the same thing. When would I use one over the other?

Here is a little more detail pseudo code:

```
    mystrand(ioservice);
    mystrand.post(myhandler1);
    mystrand.post(myhandler2);
```

this guarantees my two handlers are serialized and executed in order even in a thread pool.

Now, how is that different from below?

```
    ioservice->post(mystrand.wrap(myhandler1));
    ioservice->post(mystrand.wrap(myhandler2));
```

Seems like they do the same thing?
Why use one over the other? I see both used and am trying to figure out when
one makes more sense than the other.

Answer (score 3):

This way

```
mystrand(ioservice);
mystrand.post(myhandler1);
mystrand.post(myhandler2);
```

myhandler1 is guaranteed by mystrand to be executed before myhandler2

but

```
ioservice->post(mystrand.wrap(myhandler1));
ioservice->post(mystrand.wrap(myhandler2));
```

the execution order is the order of executing wrapped handlers, which io_service::post does not guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

`wrap` creates a callable object which, when called, will call `dispatch` on a strand.  If you don't call the object returned by `wrap`, nothing much will happen at all.  So, calling the result of `wrap` is like calling `dispatch`.  Now how does that compare to `post`?  According to the documentation, `post` differs from `dispatch` in that it does not allow the passed function to be invoked right away, within the same context (stack frame) where `post` is called.

So `wrap` and `post` differ in two ways: the immediacy of their action, and their ability to use the caller's own context to execute the given function.

I got all this by reading the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html).

Comment: Sorry I guess my question was too brief. What I meant is this:

What's the difference between: 

   ioservice->post(strand.wrap(myhandler1))
   ioservice->post(strand.wrap(myhandler2))

and

   strand.post(myhandler1) 
   strand.post(myhandler2) 
   where strand was created with ioservice.

I see both used and it seems they will do the same thing, i.e. serialize myhandler1 and myhandler2 in order?